# Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, migration

I'm running XCode 10.3 and I have several apps that were developed in Swift 3. When I open the projects I get a message saying "Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4."

The provisioning profile is about to expire for these apps so I need to update them in the next day or so.

So 2 questions:
1. Do I have to try and install an older version of XCode? or is there any way to do the migration in 10.3?
2. If I do need to install 10.1, will that affect the 10.3 install?

Comment: If you have several apps, then better use old version that supports `Swift 3` and update provisioning/certificate etc. Later, just follow what `Xcode` suggests e.g, *Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4*

Comment: but will installing the older version affect my current version or can they be installed side-by-side?

Comment: It don't think it will affect your current version.

Comment: I have an old project in Swift 3 and Xcode is advising me to "Use Xcode 10.1 to migrate the code to Swift 4". From WHERE do I download Xcode version 10.1? I really don't want to download from a 3rd party, I would like to download from Apple.